# PhpSpec - Simulate a parameter with another

Tags: php, phpspec, prophecy

I would like to know it is that possible to ignore an `Exception` in method and force to use `willReturn` method ?

I have an example:

In theory, the Transformer must have the same name of the entity (via `this->getClassName`)
But in this case, how can I do because my `SimpleEntity` and `TransformerInterface` are not the same.

```
class JsonViewTransformer
{
    private $transformers = [];

    public function testTransformer(View $view)
    {
        $entity = $view->getData();
        $this->getTransformerFromEntity($entity);
    }

    public function addTransformer(TransformerInterface $transformer)
    {
        $this->transformers[$this->getClassName($transformer)] = $transformer;
    }

    private function getTransformerFromEntity($entity)
    {
        $entityName = $this->getClassName($entity);

        if (!array_key_exists($entityName, $this->transformers)) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(sprintf('%s does not exist', $entityName), new \ErrorException());
        }

        return $this->transformers[$entityName];
    }

    private function getClassName($object)
    {
        $FQCNObject = get_class($object);
        $objectName = substr($FQCNObject, strrpos($FQCNObject, '\\') + 1);

        return $objectName;
    }
}
```

In the test file:

```
function it_returns_json_from_tranformer(View $view, SimpleEntity $entity, TransformerInterface $transformer)
{
    $entity->getId()->willReturn(1);
    $entity->getName()->willReturn('foo');
    $entity->getAge()->willReturn(42);

    $transformer->transform($entity)->willReturn([
        'id',
        'name',
        'age',
    ]);

    $view->getData()->willReturn($entity);

    $this->addTransformer($transformer);
    $this->testTransformer($view);
}
```

So I've got this error message:

```
  15  - it returns json from tranformer
      exception <label>[exc:Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException("P1 does not exist")]</label> has been thrown.
```

Have you an idea for this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you import all the classes that you stub? Looks like a use statement is missing and phpspec created a generic stub (hence "P1").

Comment: I am very surprised of you're interrogation, because you are a fu***** master with PhpSpec :) So for answer, yes and is it normal because I use `$entity` from parameters. It's a `Collaborator`. But when it's used in another argument, here `$transformer->transform($entity)`, it's become an `Px` (P1 because first argument).

Comment: I just realised you're doing some magic with extracting class name from the namespace and that's where P1 is coming from. A stub is an object that extends your original entity, and you don't allow extensions (the class name needs to match exactly what you've got on your list).

Comment: According to this line `$transformer->transform($entity)->willReturn`, `$transformer` is a mock created with `$this-> prophesize()`, right? So, maybe you have to `reveal` the real object in `$this->addTransformer($transformer->reveal());`.